# Эффект появления фиксированного меню

Tags: jquery, javascript

Нтмл

```
<nav id="fixed-header" class="default">
        <ul>
            <li class="active"><a href="#why">Почему мы</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">Коротко о нас</a></li>
            <li><a href="#program">Программы и отзывы</a></li>
            <li><a href="#action">Акции</a></li>
            <li><a href="#center">Наш центр</a></li>
            <li class="last"><a href="#contact">Контакты</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

css

```
#fixed-header.default {
    display:none; 
} 
#fixed-header.fixed {
    position: fixed;
    height: 40px;
    padding: 10px 0 1px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    background: #fff;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.85);
    z-index: 2000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 4px -4px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 6px 4px -4px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    box-shadow: 0 6px 4px -4px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
nav ul{
    width: 980px;   
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: 'segoe_uisemibold';    
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
nav ul li{
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    zoom: 1;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-right: 55px;
}
nav ul li a{    
    color: #353535;
    text-decoration: none;
}
nav ul li a:hover,
nav ul li.active a{
    color: #70B908;
}
nav ul li.last{
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

скрипт

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        var $menu = $("#fixed-header");

        $(window).scroll(function(){
            if ( $(this).scrollTop() > 300 && $menu.hasClass("default") ){
                $menu.removeClass("default").slideDown(3000).addClass("fixed");
            } else if($(this).scrollTop() <= 300 && $menu.hasClass("fixed")) {
                $menu.removeClass("fixed").addClass("default");
            }
        });
    });
```

Есть скрытое фиксированное меню, которое появляеться через 300px, все хорошо работает. но почему не работает эффект появления этого меню .slideDown(3000) - это как пример, можно и show, или fadeIn

Подскажите что не так делаю!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var $menu = $("#fixed-header");

    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if ( $(this).scrollTop() > 300 && $menu.hasClass("default") ){
            $menu.slideDown(3000).removeClass("default").addClass("fixed");
        } else if($(this).scrollTop() <= 300 && $menu.hasClass("fixed")) {
            $menu.removeClass("fixed").addClass("default");
        }
    });
});
```

Сначала ***slideDown***, а потом, что именно.

Comment: Объясните почему так?

Comment: $menu.slideDown(0).removeClass - здесь наверное так надо еще, так как при возвращении меню оно фисируеться сверху, это когда высота меньше 300 пикселей

Comment: @soledar10, Я не уверен, что логика именно в этом, но этот эффект должен распространятся только на выдвигающиеся в низ объекты.

Comment: хорошо спасибо! буду разбираться!